# Highcharts annotation outside plot area not working

Tags: highcharts

Annotations are not properly shown outside plot area. I've tried `overflow: 'none'` and `crop: false` as mentioned in Highcharts documentation, but it doesn't work.

Here's a failing example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-njxk9?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Highcharts regression bug and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12897

As a workaround overwrite `addClipPaths` function:

```
Highcharts.Annotation.prototype.addClipPaths = function() {};
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g0c71qz5/

Answer (score 0):

This bug has now been resolved since v9.3.0 by setting annotations.crop to false to disable cropping.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  
  annotations: [{
    crop: false,
    labelOptions: {
      ...
    },
  }],

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p2xh5kba/2/